# whats wrong with this jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im trying to apply a basic on click show hide element but for some reason it doesnt take no effect

im using it via an external javascript file and including the latest jquery library both included in my master page firebug shows the code so i know its picking it up

heres the code ive tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// hides the divx as soon as the DOM is ready
$('#ecom').hide();
// shows the div on clicking the noted link  
$('.eco').click(function () {
    $('#ecom').show('slow');
    return false;
});
// hides the div on clicking the noted link  
$('.eco').click(function () {
    $('#ecom').hide('fast');
    return false;
}); 
});
```

html

```
<h2 class="eco">Ecommerce Web Design</h2>
<div id="ecom">content</div>
```

I dont see the problem myself

**This was the solution i used in the end does what i want it to do :)**
Thankyou all for the answers too

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ecom').hide();
$('.eco').click(function () {
    $('#ecom').toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both handlers will fire at the same time.

I think you're looking for `.toggle()`:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/uuJPc/

```
$('.eco').toggle(function () {
    $('#ecom').show('slow');
    return false;
},function () {
    $('#ecom').hide('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Now it will alternate between clicks.

---

**EDIT:** If you were to use `.toggle()` in the manner that @Tgr mentioned below, you would need some way to distinguish between the `"slow"/"fast"` you have in your code.

Here's one way:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/uuJPc/1/

```
$('#ecom').hide();
$('.eco').click(function () {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        $('#ecom').toggle(i++ % 2 ? 'slow' : 'fast');
        return false;
    };
}());
```

or like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/uuJPc/2/

```
$('#ecom').hide();
$('.eco').click(function () {
    var ec = $('#ecom');
    ec.toggle(ec.is(':visible') ? 'slow' : 'fast');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks i tried this way initially but it still takes no effect :S

Comment: @sam: Your question states that jQuery is loaded, but is it loaded *before* your javascript loads? Or is there any chance you have more than one element on the page with the same ID `ecom`?

Comment: Or simply `$('.eco').click(function () { $('#ecom').toggle('slow'); return false; });`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/script.js") %>"></script> in that order and i tried to swap them around also if thats what you mean?

Comment: no i only have those 2 elements on that page right now its empty other than that

Comment: Are both of those two scripts actually loading, have you verified this?

Comment: @Tgr - That would work, except that OP wants `slow` for one and `fast` for the other. Though the `slow/fast` could be selected using a conditional operator. [Here's one way.](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/uuJPc/1/)

Comment: thanks tgr that code worked :) not sure why the others didnt seem to work

Comment: @Orbling - *"firebug shows the code so i know its picking it up"*. :o)

Comment: @patrick Oh yes, should really learn to read at some point. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toggle` instead of doing the whole thing manually, but that's sort a shortcut. If you're trying to learn this stuff, I recommend creating it from scratch, and only using shortcuts when you feel like you fully understand what's going on behind the scenes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide ``#ecom`` on page load.
    $('#ecom').hide();
    // Attach only one click handler (yours was attaching a handler that showed
    // the div and then on that hid the div, so it was always shown, and then
    // hidden instantly, therefore canceling your intended effect.
    $('.eco').click(function(e){
        // ``preventDefault()`` is the W3 correct way to stop event propagation
        // and works cross-browser. It's a bound method on all DOM events.
        // Notice I've given my click handler function an argument ``e``. When
        // you register an event handler function, the event that causes the
        // handler function to be called is provided as the first argument handler
        // function, thus giving us ``e`` as a local reference to the event.
        e.preventDefault();
        // Use ``is()`` to compare the element against the ``:hidden`` selector.
        // This will tell us if it's hidden or not.
        if($('#ecom').is(':hidden'))
        {
            $('#ecom').show('slow');
        } else {
            $('#ecom').hide('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not much of a stretch to figure out what `.toggle()` does. Obviously OP already knows `.show()` and `.hide()` as they are in the question. So I think it's safe to progress. Also, you're doing a duplicate DOM selection in the handler, which is a bad practice.

Comment: @patrick dw - I'm calling `$('#ecom')` twice to make the code more clear. Optimization comes last in coding, especially when you're learning. BTW, the ternary operator in your function argument makes your code very cryptic. That's the bad practice.

Comment: [ternary == cryptic == bad practice?](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L91-92) And it's a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: @patrick dw - Almost anything which is well optimized for speed and size (as jQuery's source is) is quite cryptic. jQuery is probably just as easy to read when YUI compressed :) Ternary is not bad practice in general, but using it as a function argument in your main control flow is, especially when teaching somebody, is bad practice.

Comment: @patrick dw - now you had to go and make me feel bad for being so terse, lol :) BTW, it was me to down-voted you before I posted my answer. I removed it though after you changed your answer and added more.